# Options API vs Composition API Bundling Size Comparison in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

From this article https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html I learned that Composition API has advantage `Smaller Production Bundle and Less Overhead` over Options API, but it didn't state how much smaller. Is there any Comparison for this?

Thank you in advance